# Using the new Identy server in 9.1, it is still possible to implement a custom ASP.NET Membership provider?

Tags: membership-provider, identity-server

Reading the documentation here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/sitecore-identity-server-authentication.html

"The SI server uses identityserver-contrib-membership. This project allows the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership **Database** to be used as the Identity Server User Store in IdentityServer4"

And

"You configure the connection string to the Membership database with the Sitecore:IdentityServer:SitecoreMembershipOptions:ConnectionString setting"

I get the impression that the Identity server can use user information from any domain stored in the core database, but it does not actually use the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership **Provider**, and will not use any custom membership providers (configured in web.config/membership element and domain.config)

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I'm stuck with this horrible old membership provider as it was a requirement for custom auth on sitecore a few versions ago I believe.

Comment: yes, the answer is that identity server cannot use membership providers.
As the accepted answer says, there are ways to customize the identity server (identityserver-contrib-membership is an example of that).
However it seemed more complicated, and I have not examined that more.

Comment: thanks, appreciate the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I've done a bit of research.

You are correct that the Identity server uses the user information stored in the Core database, but isn't implementing a Membership Provider and won't use a custom membership provider configured in the web.config.

The Sitecore Identity Server implements IdentityServer4. They are using [IdentityServer's Membership Service](https://github.com/sma73648/identityserver-contrib-membership) to access Membership data in an Identity context. With <strike>some</strike> a respectable effort, you could probably branch the config and add another copy of the MembershipService to the Identity Server with your own data.

I know it's also possible to disable the Identity Server entirely and fall back to the old-style login page. I'm not sure if doing that will allow you to use a Membership Provider in the usual fashion, but that should be an easy experiment to run.